# /etc/init.d/lirc doesn't exist

Tags: rpi.gpio, lirc

I am working on creating an IR remote for an older TV using my GPIO, primarily using this tutorial http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote#article_l1. However, when I get to the step that says

`sudo /etc/init.d/lirc restart`

I can't do that because that file does not exist. lircd and lircmd both exist, but as far as I can tell, they're not a replacement for lirc? If I don't need lirc, what do I need to change to use the lircd or lircmd functions instead?

Eventually, this is giving me a "hardware does not support sending" error with the command

`sudo irsend SEND_ONCE Vizio KEY_POWER`

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+

Comment: This ancient article refers to SysV, which was replaced by systemd 4 years ago

Answer (score 1):

You're using something from four years ago, before Debian/Raspbian switched from sysvinit to systemd.

Try something that isn't ancient history: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235256